# Using SharePoint Power Point Services out of the box in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

My legacy is application is developed using Sharepoint 2013, is there any way to have Power Point Service to shows BI stuffs in ASP.Net MVC application without Sharepoint.

any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

No. That service is part of SharePoint and requires SharePoint Server.

It is , however, possible to connect your local PowerPoint to your database directly and have it generate data. You can then save that PowerPoint to a server and then use an iframe to point that page to the PowerPoint file.